# DropDown Menu echo error

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a drop-down menu within a booking system that lists the events from my `SQL` database,

This is the code I have written:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * from Events";
$exeSQL = mysql_query($SQL);
while($arrayEvents = mysql_fetch_array($exeSQL));
{
    echo"<li><a href=$arrayEvents['eventName']</a></li>";
}
```

As I am new to PHP I was wondering how I can improve this and prevent the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/unix/student10/w1284519/public_html/STF/DropDown.php on line 26
```

`Line 26` is from where echo is written

EDIT: The error has been fixed thanks to your help but the code only displays three bulletpoints, how could I fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo"<li><a href=$arrayEvents['eventName']</a></li>";
```

Is a `list` not a `dropdown`, change to this:

```
echo "<select>";
while($arrayEvents = mysql_fetch_array($exeSQL))
{
    echo"<option> $arrayEvents['eventName']</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The drop-down menu now works, however it does not show the first option that is in the SQL database is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @user3527721 it should happen, try to run the query directly into your database

Comment: then the issue is not in PHP, `SELECT * from Events` gets everything from `Events` table. make sure you can query your DB properly

Answer (score 1):

You have an errant semi-colon:

```
while($arrayEvents=mysql_fetch_array($exeSQL)); <-HERE
```

Remove it

Comment: Thanks for the response! The error is still there? it says the issue is with the echo line

Comment: Try: `echo"<li><a href={$arrayEvents['eventName']}</a></li>";`

Comment: Thank you! There is now no error but no drop-down appears only 3 bullet points

Answer (score 0):

```
echo"<li><a href=" . $arrayEvents['eventName'] . "</a></li>";
```

or

```
echo"<li><a href={$arrayEvents['eventName']}</a></li>";
```

will fix the ECHO error part

Comment: Thank you for your response! The error was removed, however no drop down appears. How can I fix the code? Sorry!

Comment: Without the HTML I cannot help. Make sure you have a `<ul>` before the loop (?)